# Reference books on numerical methods for PDE and integro differential equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, soft-question, integro-differential-equations

Can you recommend a few good reference books and textbooks on **numerical analysis of partial differential** and **integro partial differential problems** that do not assume much knowledge of numerical analysis on the part of the reader?

Comment: Talk to your project advisor?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [this](http://ins.sjtu.edu.cn/people/mtang/textbook.pdf) textbook in my Numerical Analysis class; it's by Richard Burden, Douglas Faires and Annette Burden. I couldn't find the 10th edition online (for free) but the 9th edition should be good because it's free while the 10th edition isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Introduction to Numerical Analysis By: F.B. Hildebrand